# ConTeXt : strange behavior in pagella-with-euler

Tags: math-mode, fonts, context

I would like to use the pre-defined font combination pagella-with-euler. However some math glyph (apprently linked with `\displaystyle` ?) behave strangely, as you can see on this MWE :

```
\setupbodyfont[pagella-with-euler]

\starttext
Bonjour les ami·e·s
\startformula
  x + 3 = \mathcal{P}
  \qquad
  \sqrt{a}
  \qquad
  \startmathcases
    \NC a = b \NC case 1 \NR
    \NC a = c \NC case 2 \NR
    \NC a = d \NC case 3 \NR
  \stopmathcases
  \qquad
  \left{ x = 3 + \sqrt{a} \right}
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

[image]

Has anyone an idea about how to avoid this ? If this is inherently in the font I might not be able to use it…

Thank you in advance,

Comment: The problem is that the two different fonts don't use the same Unicode snippets (pagella uses private snippets) for the extensible delimiters. Hans is aware of it, so I think it will be fixed in the next upload. (I do not see the big square roots here.)

Answer (score 1):

Lines 49–51 of `type-imp-euler.mkxl` are:

```
    \starttypescript [\s!math] [euleroverpagella] [\s!name]
        \definefontsynonym [\s!MathRoman] [texgyrepagella-math] [\s!features={\s!math\mathsizesuffix,euleroverpagella,mathextra},\s!fallbacks=euleroverpagella,\s!goodies=pagella-math]
    \stoptypescript
```

This loads only the Pagella goodies file, which sets incorrect values for the Euler delimiters. Changing this to:

```
    \starttypescript [\s!math] [euleroverpagella] [\s!name]
        \definefontsynonym [\s!MathRoman] [texgyrepagella-math] [\s!features={\s!math\mathsizesuffix,euleroverpagella,mathextra},\s!fallbacks=euleroverpagella,\s!goodies=euler-math]
    \stoptypescript
```

fixes this specific problem. However, this will likely cause other issues since the Euler goodies will now be used for any of the fallback Pagella characters. A proper solution to this will probably end up in an update sooner or later.

Comment: This hack re-changes the \mathcal{P} into the pagella character, wich I dislike… it seems there is no way to have it consistently in the short term.